# How do I extract numbers from a string in VB6?

Tags: vb6

I have a string that looks something like 'NS-BATHROOMS   04288'

I only want the numbers.

I hve searched for answers, but none so far even get pst the compiler.

How can I do this?

Comment: Always the *last* group of digits? What for `XXX6-TOILET 1234` ?

Answer (score 2):

without regex you can do it with: (altough VB6/VBA Code really isn`t nice to look at)

```
Public Function ReturnNonAlpha(ByVal sString As String) As String  
   Dim i As Integer  
   For i = 1 To Len(sString)  
       If Mid(sString, i, 1) Like "[0-9]" Then  
           ReturnNonAlpha = ReturnNonAlpha + Mid(sString, i, 1)  
       End If  
   Next i  
End Function
```

Comment: Don't use `+` when you mean `&` because it is a poor habit that can leads to unexpected results.  The compiler has to guess at your intent.  Also you can use `"#"` as the `Like` pattern for matching a digit.  But almost anything is going to outperform the obscurity of regex, which was never meant for use anywhere but scripting languages.

Comment: No need for the "regex" either. Just use `IsNumeric()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally use regex. You can match given regex patterns to achieve what you need. This function matches only digits.

For VB6 you'd do something like:

```
Dim myRegExp, ResultString
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.Global = True
myRegExp.Pattern = "[\d]"
```

Then you'd go against your String.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/818802

Comment: Your regular expression is incorrect. The carat (^) inside the brackets negates the \d digit expression so all it will match is the non-digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function for extract numerical chr as string value:

```
Public Function Str_To_Int(MyString As Variant) As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim X As Variant
If IsNull(MyString) Or MyString = "" Then
Str_To_Int = 0
Exit Function
End If
For i = 1 To Len(MyString)
If IsNumeric(Mid(MyString, i, 1)) = True Then
X = Nz(X, "") & Mid(MyString, i, 1)
End If
Next i
Str_To_Int = Nz(X, 0)
End Function
```